# Dreamhost script killed

Tags: php, web-hosting, dreamhost

I'm using Dreamhost. In one of my scripts I need to gather contents of url (using file_get_contents). There are 9 sites, 8 of them are ok but one is very slow. It tooks 10~30sec. to connect.

As you would know scripts running more than ~5 seconds are killed by Dreamhost happy killer. So I cant gather this site.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Switch to a decent host.

Comment: `scripts running more than ~5 secs. are killed by dreamhost happy killer` <-- Really? That's news to me, and I've been using DH with scripts which run longer than that for years....

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about mass, The error was in regexp, My laptop could handle but dreamhost caused problem. I changed it to basic str_replace and now it survives.